# When Kafka sends multiple batches in the same request?

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka sends a Batch as soon as `batch.size` of bytes is collected or `linger.ms` time has passed.

Then how come there can be multiple Batches in a single request? Does it mean that when Kafka is ready to send a Batch for one partition, Batches for other partitions would be closed and sent in the same request?

Doesn't it affect compression efficiency for the Batches that were not closed by `batch.size` or `linger.ms` ?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "Then how come there can be multiple Batches in a single request"? Where did you read this or is it an assumption/observation?

Comment: the max.request.size parameter says to "limit the number of record batches in a single request" - https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs_max.request.size
After investigating the code, it looks that indeed Kafka will send all the batches it can fit into request for specific node (answered my own question).
Thank you for responding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating the [source code](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/f91d592a270dc4254978fbdb51e9cd479426b931/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/internals/Sender.java#L360) it looks like when there is data ready to be sent to a node (at least one batch for partition of this node is ready), then Sender will take for each partition of the node the **ready** batch that fits into request and sends them all.
So if the batch is not yet "ready" (by bytes or by time) it is not included in the batch. So the compression rates are not affected.

Comment: Which version  do you investigating?with 1.0 I think if  just one batch is ready, all batch who's leader is the same broker  will be send  to the broker together.